# why I have to re-declare type when implement interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

why typescript throw error when I already declare type in interface.

[image: implement interface]

Playgroud:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QDwC5kQBXAWwCNpkAfE0gG0YG4c8BnCMADQAoAbnEbEyVaAEpiAgPbAAJmwC+WLAkZwOHZACFkwcgAdGEchHDb02PMgD0tgsgC8DZi1z3kAHgC0f5GAAFsDaAO7AzCQyYMjkcADWKAAGXLxJAYFQMqHI0FlQ7LhEDOJQdK6MzhVshcip-EIiJdRQEpi1NkEhAHT4VY1sNipKQA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define implementation of `x` in the class. Interface definition only defines "shape" of an object.

TypeScript cannot know how you want to implement the `x`. For example, instead of using field, you could have valid implementation of `A` interface using getter, setter and backing field:

```js
class B implements A {
    private _x: number | null = null;

    get x(): number | null {
        return this._x;
    };

    set x(value: number | null) {
        this._x = value;
    }

    setX(val: number) {
        this.x = val;
    }
}
```

Typescript playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QDwC5kQBXAWwCNpkAfE0gG0YG4c8BnCMADQAoAbnEbEyVaAEpiAgPbAAJmwC+WLAkZwOHZACFkwcgAdGEchHDb02PMkNRgQyMgD6RBuKh0GzZAF5vrKo2AObcBHxS7tSe9GQ+1jZ4UNykUCDIYAAWwBwAdK5sNkps7LhcYOFCjKQQohTRXnGMEpiliVk5+fh+yFU1hXgqbeX8VXUeLQmJGdl53f5VA7gqSkA).

Answer (score 0):

When your class is implementing interface then it **doesn't mean that properties from an interface have been already declared in a class**. All that interface is doing here for you it's just checking your types in class:

Ok:

```
class B implements A {
    x: number | null = null;
    ...
}
```

Not ok:

```
class B implements A {
    x: number | string= "";
    ...
}
```

But you can't use 'x' without declaring it in class and you have declared it in class as null which matches the type number | null. An interface is **only to check types used in class**, not further implementation.